# Hive Group by Optimization

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am creating aggregates over some dimensions in hive. The problem that I face is the aggregate query is taking close to 5 hours to aggregate around 40G of data and the logs show that there is a huge skew in the data.

I can some how find an alternative for skew in join, but not sure if I can avoid the same while calculating aggregates.

Even the bucketing would create only the buckets for the groups, and the situation still persists. Is there any better mechanism to handle these scenarios.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your query to see if there is some optimization potential.

Comment: set hive.groupby.skewindata=true;

Comment: set hive.map.aggr=true;